# Convert buffer array into a useable string using Arduino?( for connecting processing)

Tags: c++, arduino, processing

for the previous code, the serial monitor will get the message is hexadecimal like"08000AE23BDB",but in Processing those data just show as "NaN".I think maybe only string can be got for processing? but" String buffer(buffer[count])" seems can`t work,how can I convert it?

following is the code of arduino:

```
   #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial SoftSerial(2, 3);
unsigned char buffer[64]; // buffer array for data recieve over serial port
int count=0;     // counter for buffer array 

void setup()
{
  SoftSerial.begin(9600);               // the SoftSerial baud rate   
  Serial.begin(9600);             // the Serial port of Arduino baud rate.

}

void loop()
{

  if (SoftSerial.available())              // if date is comming from softwareserial port ==> data is comming from SoftSerial shield
  {
    while(SoftSerial.available())          // reading data into char array 
    {
      buffer[count++]=SoftSerial.read();     // writing data into array
      if(count == 64)break;
    }

    Serial.write(buffer,count);         // if no data transmission ends, write buffer to hardware serial port
    clearBufferArray();              // call clearBufferArray function to clear the storaged data from the array
    count = 0;                       // set counter of while loop to zero
  }
  if (Serial.available())            // if data is available on hardwareserial port ==> data is comming from PC or notebook
  {
    SoftSerial.write(Serial.read());       // write it to the SoftSerial shield
  }

}
void clearBufferArray()              // function to clear buffer array
{
  for (int i=0; i<count;i++){
    { 
      buffer[i]=NULL;
    }
  }                  // clear all index of array with command NULL
}
```

and this is the getting massage part of Processing:

```
void serialEvent(Serial myPort) { 

  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');  

  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);

    float[] data = float(split(inString, ","));

    if (data.length >=1) 
    {
      direction1 = data[0];
    }
    println("data");
    println(data[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what `trim` and `split` do, what type `data` is, and an example of what's in `inString`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
 String inString = "08000AE23BDB ";

  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);

    String[] data = split(inString, ",");

    if (data.length >=1) 
    {
      //direction1 = data[0];
    }
    println(unhex(data[0]));
  }
```